# RGDAL installation error: libnetcdf.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, gdal, netcdf

I run RStudio Server on ubuntu 14.04. When trying to install the rgdal  package I get the following error message:

> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
>     unable to load shared object '/home/admin2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-  library/2.14/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
>     libnetcdf.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   Error: loading failed
>   Execution halted

I upgraded RStudio Server, R-Core and all Ubuntu packages to their latest versions but no success. I also tried `apt-get install lib32stdc++6` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471722/libstdc-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory), but also no changes. I think it is a problem specific to GDAL and the indexing of [shared libraries](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Shared-Libraries.html) in unix. Can anyone help please?

Comment: When you updated to the last version of R, your library should not be in `/2.14/` but in `3.3`.

Comment: @J_F: I changed that as well. but it still does not work.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333097/got-message-unable-to-load-shared-object-stats-so-when-r-starts) will help you.

Comment: Try (re)installing the `ncdf4` R-package.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it done removing Gdal completly, compiling it from source again and setting library paths correctly as described [here](https://gist.github.com/lossyrob/4348503). Later adding `/usr/local/lib/` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run `sudo ldconfig` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104224/geodjango-gdal-library-giving-error).