# How to query Django PostGIS / Postgres DB with the map / Leaflet boundary box view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, leaflet, postgis, geodjango

Results from query made with other fields are populated on Leaflet:

```js
var myMap = L.map("mapid", {zoomControl: false});
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {maxZoom: 18 }).addTo(myMap); myMap.setView([-34, 151], 12);
var markers = [
{% for journal in queryset %}
    L.marker([{{ journal.latitude }}, {{ journal.longitude }}]),
{% endfor %}
]
var group = L.featureGroup(markers).addTo(myMap);
```

I now want the results populated by where the user places Leaflet's boundary box, but I'm bewildered on how to do that. I've [got GDAL installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69775260/django-geodjango-cant-find-the-gdal-library-on-ubuntu-dokku/69811317#69811317), have converted the long / lat cols to a spatial col in Postgis with `ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point, 4326) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint("longitude", "latitude"), 4326)) STORED`, added `geom = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)` to models.py, but am lost on where to go from here.

[This seems the most authoritative tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEivCtavw-I&t=695s) on the topic but I'm totally lost when he gets to views and talks of a generic class based view / list views / Django Rest Framework. Is there a dumbed down explanation somewhere? I feel like an idiot.

Unsure if relevant but the table isn't managed by Django.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, although the solution is far more complicated than I initially understood.

[This tutorial](https://www.paulox.net/2021/07/19/maps-with-django-part-2-geodjango-postgis-and-leaflet/) by the same guy who made the video was helpful. Please see the tutorial as he gives a better explanation than I can.

Also, I couldn't find anything anywhere on installing the [PostgreSQL C Client library](https://www.paulox.net/2021/07/19/maps-with-django-part-2-geodjango-postgis-and-leaflet/#installing-postgresql-c-client-library) or what he installs as `libpq5` on Win10, but it seems this was unneeded, perhaps because it might already be installed with Postgres.